# Switch between 2 ng-shows

Tags: angularjs

I have two elements with a ng-show in them,

```
%a.follow{"ng-click" => "followUser(user)", "ng-show" => "!isFollowed(user.id)"} follow
%a.unfollow{"ng-click" => "unfollowUser(user)", "ng-show" => "isFollowed(user.id)"} unfollow
```

It depends on the `user.id` which ng-show is being rendered in the template. So only one of the two ng-shows is displayed.

So for example a user wants to start following another user. Then the `follow` link is displayed.

```
%a.follow{"ng-click" => "followUser(user)", "ng-show" => "!isFollowed(user.id)"} follow
```

When a user clicks on it, I would like to hide the clicked ng-show, and show the `unfollow` ng-show so that the user can unfollow the just followed user.

The follow and unfollow user function,

```
$scope.followUser = function (user) {
  followUser.create({
    followed_id: user.id
  }).then(init);
  Notification.success(user.name + ' is toegevoegd als vriend.');
}

$scope.unfollowUser = function(user){
  unfollowUser.unfollowUser(user).then(function(){
  },function(){
  }).then(init);
  Notification.success(user.name + ' is verwijderd als vriend.');
}
```

And the isFollowed function,

```
usersService.loadUsers().then(function(response) {
  $scope.users = response.data;
  console.log ($scope.users)

  angular.forEach(response, function(user){
    $scope.user = user

    $scope.isFollowed = function(userId) {
      var following = $scope.current_user.following;
      for (var i=0; i<following.length; i++) {
        if (following[i].id == userId) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  })
})
```

I've tried building this,

```
<a ng-click="follow=false ;unfollow=true", ng-show="follow">Follow!</a>
<a ng-click="follow=true; unfollow=false", ng-show="unfollow">Unfollow!</a>
```

This does switch between the two ng-shows, but when I try to get the `isFollowed(user.id)`, `!isFollowed(user.id)` in them the code crashes.

Comment: Show us the three functions: `followUser(user)`, `unfollowUser(user)`, and `isFollowed(id)`. What have you tried? And what problems are you having? Is this being done in an `ng-repeat`? Are you sending and waiting for a response from a server?

Comment: and what is there in `followUser` & `unfollowUser` method.show that.

Comment: I've updated the question with some more code, and an exampe of what I've tried.

Comment: I think you can use `ng-switch`, for more reference [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch).

Comment: @MihailStancescu I was just looking at it, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inlutXtys4w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create single function to follow/unfollow, Here in the code snippet I have introduced a new property i.e. `isFollowed` to object `user` whose value is set using the `isFollowed` function.

Additionally, Don't overuse `isFollowed(user.id)` method, it will be huge performance hit.

*HTML*

```
<a ng-click="followUnfollowUser(user)"> {{ user.isFollowed : "Unfollow!" : "Follow!"}}  </a>
```

*Script*

```
$scope.followUnfollowUser = function(user) {
    //If followed - unfollow
    if (user.isFollowed) {
        unfollowUser.unfollowUser(user).then(function() {
            user.isFollowed=!user.isFollowed
        }, function() {
        }).then(init);

        Notification.success(user.name + ' is verwijderd als vriend.');
    } else {

        followUser.create({
            followed_id: user.id
        }).then(function() {
            user.isFollowed=!user.isFollowed
        }, function() {
        }).then(init);

        Notification.success(user.name + ' is toegevoegd als vriend.');
    }
}

//Define method to check wheather current user is beign followed
var isFollowed = function(userId) {
    var following = $scope.current_user.following;
    for (var i = 0; i < following.length; i++) {
        if (following[i].id == userId) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//Fetch Users
usersService.loadUsers().then(function(response) {
    $scope.users = response.data;
    //Iterate and create isFollowed property
    angular.forEach($scope.users, function(user) {
        user.isFollowed = isFollowed(user.id);
    })
})
```

Note: I'm not familiar with following syntax thus used standard HTML.

```
%a.follow{"ng-click" => "followUser(user)", "ng-show" => "!isFollowed(user.id)"} follow
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. But I don't see how this code would update the view.

Comment: Sorry, the .init used to reload the users. But since there's no change in users if you follow or unfollow a user it doesn't update the view.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma, Notice `user.isFollowed = isFollowed(user.id);` in `usersService.loadUsers()` function, which will update the new property which is used

Comment: Alright. Something is happening! The `{{ user.isFollowed }}` goes from `false` to `true` when the link is clicked, but when `{{ user.isFollowed }}` is `true` it doesn't go to `false`, it stays `true` untill I refresh the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99679/discussion-between-peter-boomsma-and-satpal).

Answer (score 0):

Alrhgout Satpal did point me to the right direction and helped me with some code. His answer isn't complete. So I've decided that add the code I'm using for this function (made with the help of Satpal!).

I've created a `followUnfollowUser` function. But instead of having two `.then(init)` I have one `init()` at the end of the function. Having the two inits gave me some looping trouble.

```
$scope.followUnfollowUser = function(user) {
    //If followed - unfollow
    if (user.isFollowed) {

        unfollowUser.unfollowUser(user).then(function() {
            user.isFollowed=!user.isFollowed
        }, function() {
        })

        Notification.success(user.name + ' is verwijderd als vriend.');

    } else {

        followUser.create({
            followed_id: user.id
        }).then(function() {
            user.isFollowed=!user.isFollowed
        }, function() {
        })

        Notification.success(user.name + ' is toegevoegd als vriend.');
    }
  init();
}
```

Then the `init` function,

```
var init = function () {

  loadCurrent_user.loadCurrent_user().then(function(response) {
    $scope.current_user = response.data;
  });

  usersService.loadUsers().then(function(response) {
    $scope.users = response.data;
    //Iterate and create isFollowed property
    angular.forEach($scope.users, function(user) {
      user.isFollowed = isFollowed(user.id);
    })
  })

  var isFollowed = function(userId) {

    var following = $scope.current_user.following;
    for (var i = 0; i < following.length; i++) {
      if (following[i].id == userId) {
          return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

First I load the current user so that the `$scope.current_user` gets updated when a user is being followed/unfollowed. And then I iterate through each user and create the isFollowed value using the isFollowed function.

And in my template I have,

```
%a{"ng-click" => "followUnfollowUser(user)"}
  -# {{ user.isFollowed }}
  {{ user.isFollowed ? "Unfollow user" : "Follow user"}}
```